# Unix: Rename file with dynamic extension

Tags: regex, linux, unix, rename

I am using RHEL 5.10 and I am trying to remove dynamic date extension from a bunch of files.

The file format is like `filename01.gz.20160704`, where the last part `date` is dynamic. I want it to be renamed to `filename01.gz`

When I try to rename like below, it works

```
rename   gz.20160704   gz   filename01.gz.20160704
```

Output: `filename01.gz`

But when I try to rename like this it doesn't work

```
rename  gz.*  gz  filename01.gz.20160704
```

I tried searching other answer and in some of them, they used rename like below, but sadly that is also not working for me.

```
rename 's/gz*/gz/' filename01.gz.20160704   
rename 's/gz.*/gz/' filename01.gz.20160704
```

The `man` page for my linux says

> ```
> For example, given the files foo1, ..., foo9, foo10, ..., foo278, the commands
>           rename foo foo0 foo?
>           rename foo foo0 foo??
> ```

Could someone please help me with it or is there any alternative approach I can use?

---

Update: Added the solution given by @PSkocik but it is not working either.

```
$> ls -ltr filename01*
-rw-rw----+ 1 foo foo 0 Jul  4 08:34 filename01.gz.20160704
$> rename -n 's/\.gz\.[^.]*/.gz/' filename01.gz.*
$> echo $?
0
$> ls -ltr filename01*
-rw-rw----+ 1 foo foo 0 Jul  4 08:34 filename01.gz.20160704
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. with `prename` (perl-rename):

   ```
   rename -n 's/\.gz\.[^.]*/.gz/' filename01.gz.*
   ```
2. with mv and a POSIX shell:

   ```
   for f in *.gz.*; do mv "$f" "${f%.*}"; done
   ```

Comment: Sadly it is not working either. I updated by question with the screen grep of your solution.

Comment: If I do `touch filename01.gz.20160704` and then the above command, I get `filename01.gz.20160704 renamed as filename01.gz` as expected. My `rename` is a link to `/usr/bin/prename` (perl rename). There should be another `rename` utility with different syntax (see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98070/rename-files-in-directory), but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any `prename` on my RHEL machine. Lets see if I/someone else can find a way, else I would write a shell and put `date` in a variable and use that, which should work. Anyways thanks for the answer.

Comment: Aah. `for f in *.gz.*; do mv "$f" "${f%.*}"; done` did the trick! Thanks a ton. You saved my day.